# Unity Bing Speech sample

Tags: unity-game-engine, azure-cognitive-services, bing-speech

i would like to use Bing speech services to my unity project.
I am already using LUIS and windows.speech for TextToSpeech and SpeechToText.

But i found no sample and i tried to integrate BibnSpeech to my project but i always have namescape or c# version issues.

Does someone have a simple sample of Bing speech in unity or just how to integrate this project https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/tree/master/Samples-Http/CSharp

to unity pls ?

thx for any advice =) (currently using unity 5.5.2f1)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I will also point out that Unity uses .NET 2.0 and if that library is not compatible with .NET 2.0, you're going to have trouble no one can fix.